# Get bounding box coordinates (xywh) from quad coordinates and normalize them

Tags: python, opencv, bounding-box

I have photos and coordinates of objects within those photos.

For example:

```
        {
          "shape_attributes": {
            "name": "polygon",
            "all_points_x": [613, 2007, 1769, 581],
            "all_points_y": [1767, 1674, 2260, 2395]
          },
          "region_attributes": {"field_name": "doc_quad"}
        }
```

I need to convert them to 4 points:

```
 x_center y_center width height
```

to get a bounding box. After that I need to normalize them following this instructions:

```
Box coordinates must be in normalized xywh format (from 0 - 1). If your boxes are in pixels, divide x_center and width by image width, and y_center and height by image height.
```

How to convert 8 pointed polygon coordinates into normalized form (with 4 points)?

This question might require some geometry knowledge and you can send a link for a related article, If you find this question too easy. The thing is I don't know how to ask Google a question to find an answer, because `How to convert 8 point polygon coordinates into 4 point rectangle coordinates` didn't give me results I want (majority of articles I found assume that I don't know actual coordinates and use some detection functions from `opencv`, but I do know actual coordinates) that's why I'm asking here.

Comment: your polygon isn't "8 pointed". it's four-pointed, and each point consists of two values. and you need to *try* to solve your problem first. please review the [tour] and [ask] to improve your chances of a decent answer.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I got the answer below. I *tried* to solve the problem first and did google search. I'm asking because I could not figure it out myself. Does it make sense?

Comment: honestly, no. putting a box around four points... you should have recognized that you need to work with `min()` and `max()`, and the center of that box is just... it's all basic math. high school math. in any case, you got an answer and you even got the code written for you, and debating this isn't gonna lead anywhere.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I agree that's very simple question, but not everyone in this world has the same knowledge like you do. I could not understand that those 8 numbers represent 4 points and not 8 points. I didn't ask for *code* , but for a way of solving the problem. I even asked to provide some links. Now I have a visualisation and understand that was a simple question.

Answer (score 4):

Since the polygon is not rectangular, one way is to take a bounding box that covers all points inside, or a tight rectangle that is covered by all points. Below is the first method.

```
"all_points_x": [613, 2007, 1769, 581]
"all_points_y": [1767, 1674, 2260, 2395]
```

Though the graph `(0,0)` is at bottom left and image `(0,0)` point starts at top left the idea is same. Only top and bottom horizontal lines in my graph reference are flipped for image.

**The graph is here, https://www.desmos.com/calculator/bzhbyrgz3o**

[image]

Take the max of `all_points_x` to get the right most vertical line and take minimum of `all_points_x` to get left most vertical line. Similarly take max and min of `all_points_y` to get top and bottom horizontal line.

```
p2 = max([613,2007,1769,581]) = 2007
p1 = min([613,2007,1769,581]) = 581
q2 = max([1767,1674,2260,2395]) = 2395
q1 = min([1767,1674,2260,2395]) = 1674
```

Get center point `(cx,cy)` by,

```
cx = (p1 + p2) / 2 = 1294
cy = (q1 + q2) / 2 = 2034.5
```

Get width, height, `(w,h)` by,

```
w = p2 - p1 = 1426
h = q2 - q1 = 721
```

Now if the image is `(im_w, im_h)` then the normalized format will be,

```
cx_new = cx / im_w
w_new = w / im_w
cy_new = cy / im_h 
h_new = h / im_h
```

So the 4 numbers are,

```
cx_new cy_new w_new h_new
```

This format `x_center y_center width height` is used by YOLO. [This link](https://albumentations.ai/docs/getting_started/bounding_boxes_augmentation/#yolo) should be helpful.

Comment: good answer, but consider what behavior you are rewarding. you just wrote his code for him.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz ffs. I won't use the *code* ! He explained the thing I could not figure out. "8 numbers == coordinates for 4 points", that's all I needed.

Answer (score 0):

is it okay to find minimum covered regtangle from

--> min(x),min(y) max(x),max(y)

Comment: Could you please elaborate abit? I have 8 points, but your method requires 4 arguments